# Have to create a huge complicated list comprehension to create dictionary of list of ASCII values in Python, cannot use for loop outside of list comp

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

> The following is my code so far along with the instructions in a docstring.

```
def get_word_codes(words):
"""Given a list of words, return a dictionary where the words are keys,
    and the value for each key is a list of the character codes of the
    letters of the word that is its key."""
[print(ascii(words.index(x))) for x in word in words]
```

> Obviously, this code is wrong, but I have worked on it for hours. I know I seem pathetic, but in my defense, my teacher wants me to print the entire code in just one list comprehension. Obviously, she says that for this exercise, she wants us to use PEP8 as a guide. And I know how I need to split up the code into several lines to make it more readable and presentable. That's not a problem. The problem is I am pretty sure that this list comprehension will be ridiculously long. Please, please help. I am very grateful for any help you can give.
> Here's how the function should work, if it works correctly:

```
words = ['yes', 'no']

codes = get_word_codes(words)

codes {'yes': [121, 101, 115], 'no': [110, 111]}

words = ['hello', 'python', 'bye']

codes = get_word_codes(words)

codes {'hello': [104, 101, 108, 108, 111], 'python': [112, 121, 116, 104, 111, 110], 'bye': [98, 121,
101]}

codes = get_word_codes(['Python is fun!'])

codes {'Python is fun!': [80, 121, 116, 104, 111, 110, 32, 105, 115, 32, 102, 117, 110, 33]}
```

So each word in the list is turned into a key, and each letter in each word is the value, but the value should be the ASCII value of the letter.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Please provide a working demo in multiple lines and we can condense it from there. Include function, input, and output.

Comment: So here's how the function should work, if it works correctly:words = ['yes', 'no']
>>> codes = get_word_codes(words)
>>> codes
{'yes': [121, 101, 115], 'no': [110, 111]}
>>> words = ['hello', 'python', 'bye']
>>> codes = get_word_codes(words)
>>> codes
{'hello': [104, 101, 108, 108, 111], 'python': [112, 121, 116, 104, 111, 110], 'bye': [98, 121,
101]}
codes = get_word_codes(['Python is fun!'])
>>> codes
{'Python is fun!': [80, 121, 116, 104, 111, 110, 32, 105, 115, 32, 102, 117, 110, 33]}

Comment: Please edit your original question.  The previous paragraph is unreadable.  In general, putting lines of code into comments doesn't work.

Comment: You need to use a dictionary comprehension for this. Split the problem up, first figure out the dictionary comprehension with the words as keys, then figure out the list comprehension to turn a word into a list of character codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for dictionaries. Iterate through your list to separate words. Then use list comprehension inside to build a list of ascii values with `ord()`.

```
def get_word_codes(words):
    """Given a list of words, return a dictionary where the words are keys,
    and the value for each key is a list of the character codes of the
    letters of the word that is its key."""
    return {word:[ord(x) for x in word] for word in words}

print(get_word_codes(["this", "is", "a", "list", "of", "words"]))
```

**Output:**

```
{'this': [116, 104, 105, 115], 'is': [105, 115], 'a': [97], 'list': [108, 105, 115, 116], 'of': [111, 102], 'words': [119, 111, 114, 100, 115]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Wow! I have to study how ord() works in depth! Thank you to EVERYONE who responded, but thank you especially to you! Both of you love what you do, I can tell! I LOVE programming, and I am so grateful to receive help from people who don't look down on beginners and refuse to help! THANK YOU BOTH!!

Comment: Having a function readily available makes this a perfect use case for `map`: `return {word:[*map(ord, word)] for word in words}`

Answer (score 0):

it can be implemented in following way

```py
def get_word_codes(words: list) -> dict:
    return dict([(word, [ord(char) for char in word]) \
        for word in words])



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_word_codes(["Hello", "World"]))
```

if you want to understand it : we used pythons built-in function `ord()` in order to get ascii value of char in string created a tuple having key value pair as its elements so that passing it to `dict` creates desired dict.

Comment: output is:{'Hello': [72, 101, 108, 108, 111], 'World': [87, 111, 114, 108, 100]}